# .net core 3.1 docker container extremely slow response

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nginx, amazon-ec2

We had a few API which were hosted in AWS Elastic beanstalk. we decided to combine all of those applications in a single EC2 instance under individual docker container in order to isolate their environments. 
After the setup I have ran into a performance issue. the response time is extremely slow (~58 sec)

I looked at the docker stats but memory is not hogging, CPU is not spiking, all seems to be normal there. This is not a new application we have been using this application for over an year now.

Let me share my docker file contents and the way I have built it and the command I used to run the images.

**EC2 instance:** t3a.small in us-east-1 region

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
COPY release_dll/  /root/
WORKDIR /root/
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:80" 
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "vizdom.webapi.dll"]
```

**Docker build command:** `sudo docker build -t ss-webapi .`

**Docker run command:** `sudo docker run -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Dev -itd --network=ss-subnet  --ip 172.18.0.3 ss-webapi`

**ss-subnet** network uses bridge mode drivers.

On the same machine there is nginx reverse proxy which routes the requests to individual containers

**For example:**

```
location /webapi{
rewrite ^/webapi(.*) $1 break;
proxy_pass http://172.18.0.3:80;
proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_buffering off;
}
```

I dont know what can be done to improve the speed. I doubt it is something related to network but not sure enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue has been traced.
My API are hosted in us-east-1 region whereas I was trying to access the data in the ap-southeast-1 region due to that there was a latency. I will be moving all the resources in a single region in order to reduce the cost and latency issue.